# How can I set default translate i18n in nuxt js?

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I had set default `it`  in `nuxt.config.js` like this :

[image]

But if I access localhost it  redirect to : `http://localhost:3000/en`
Should it redirect to `http://localhost:3000/`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you have used language feature (nuxt-i18n) thats why the path is little different. and by default it is in english language mode. if you dont want to use that then you have to remove language feature. then you will get the url http://localhost:3000/

Comment: @Md Mahamudul Hasan I need language feature. Because my website support 2 language. I had solve this problem. I add `detectBrowserLanguage: false`, it works

Comment: exactly, you are right

Comment: I'm curious @SuccessMan, why would you like to disable the `detectBrowserLanguage` feature? If someone has a browser configured in English, why would you redirect him to Italian ?

Comment: @bmartins Because I want the default language in my project is Italian. I had set `defaultLocale: 'it'`, but it does not works. So I set `detectBrowserLanguage: false` to solve my problem

Answer (score 5):

You should use **detectBrowserLanguage** Like this :

> For example default locale set to FR

```
[
  'nuxt-i18n',
  {
    locales: ['fr', 'en'],
    defaultLocale: 'fr',
    detectBrowserLanguage: false,
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
      messages: {
        fr: {
          index:'home'
        },
        en: {
          index:'Index'
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
```